# What's the best way to extract links to images from CSS files with PHP?

Tags: php, css, image, parsing

I want to find all links to images from a CSS file.

E.g.

```
background-image: url(images/abc123.jpg);
```

I've found a PHP class called [CSS parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html) but it doesn't seem to have a very large API.  Is there a better CSS parser about?

I need to be able to modify the links in the file after I have extracted them too.

Thanks.

Comment: can you use preg_match and preg_replace? should be a pretty easy regex for that case.

Comment: The only problem is, there are a lot of different ways of specifying an image url in CSS.  I was hoping there would be a nice parser which would do all the hard work for me.

Comment: There actually aren't that many. Every image ends with a .jpg, .gif, or .png right? So your regex will be like /(.*\.[png|gif|jpg]/

Comment: Yes, but it could be `background-image: url(image.jpg);` or `background-image: url('image.jpg');` or `background-image: url("image.jpg");` or `background: #ffffff url('image.jpg')` or... You see my point?  The plot thickens.

Comment: yeah its true, but I was thinking just start from the opening parens. You dont need colors so those get ignored, but yeah I mean, best would be a fancy css parser to just do it for you but as a last resort, Im pretty sure it wouldnt be that hard to regex it.

Comment: But that's not importat! It's always the same `url(here it is)`. So it's really pretty simple. The `"` and `'` could be optional in your regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getImageUrls($input_string) {
   $matches = array();
   preg_match_all('/url\((.+?)\);/i', $input_string, $matches);
   return preg_replace('/url\((.+?)\);/i', '$1', $matches);
}
```

something like that anyways. pull the matches out and then format them to keep only the url path.

Comment: you could also run through the array and pull out any quote marks.

Comment: i'd suggest get rid of the semicolon in the expression, because many times background images are written like this: `background: url(xxx.png) no-repeat;`